# Problems with OAuth2 and gspread

Tags: google-sheets, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, gspread

I've had some working api code for quite a long time but suddenly (about 30 minutes from the previous use of the api) it's stopped working
here's the traceback

```
 row_cells = self.range('%s:%s' % (start_cell, end_cell))
 File"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/models.py", line 72, in wrapper
return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/models.py", line 412, in range
params={'range': name, 'return-empty': 'true'}
File     "/Lbrary/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 176, in get_cells_feed
r = self.session.get(url)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/httpsession.py", line 73, in get
return self.request('GET', url, params=params, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/httpsession.py", line 69, in request
response.status_code, response.content))
gspread.exceptions.RequestError: (401, '401: b\'<HTML>\\n<HEAD>\\n<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>\\n</HEAD>\\n<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">\\n<H1>Unauthorized</H1>\\n<H2>Error 401</H2>\\n</BODY>\\n</HTML>\\n\'')
```

And I don't really understand this...

here's the code

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import pprint


scope = [ 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds' ]


creds =  ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)


client = gspread.authorize(creds)


sheet = client.open('sheet_name').sheet1
```

I really don't know what to do, I've already created new api's email address, downloaded the json file (client_secret.json) but it still didn't get back to working and I honestly don't know why

Comment: Did you also try generating a new service account key?

Comment: Yes, I've generated whole new credentials

Comment: make the email the owner of the document